# Choose an item from Combo box in Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to choose an item from a drop down list in Selenium Java

HTML

```
<div class="aui-ss aui-ss-has-entity-icon" id="issueTypeKey-single-select" data-query=""><input autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="text aui-ss-field ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" id="issueTypeKey-field" type="text"><div class="ajs-layer-placeholder"><div class="ajs-layer box-shadow" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 53px; position: absolute; left: 759px; top: 302px; max-height: 328px; display: none;"><div class="aui-list" id="issueTypeKey-suggestions" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" style="display: block;"><div class="aui-list-scroll" tabindex="-1" role="presentation"><ul class="aui-last"><li class="aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-purchase active" role="option" id="purchase-1"><a class="aui-list-item-link aui-iconised-link" role="presentation" href="#"><img class="icon" alt="" src="/servicedesk/issue-type-icons?icon=purchase">Purchase</a></li><li class="aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-fault" role="option" id="fault-2"><a class="aui-list-item-link aui-iconised-link" role="presentation" href="#"><img class="icon" alt="" src="/servicedesk/issue-type-icons?icon=fault">Fault</a></li><li class="aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-access" role="option" id="access-3"><a class="aui-list-item-link aui-iconised-link" role="presentation" href="#"><img class="icon" alt="" src="/servicedesk/issue-type-icons?icon=access">Access</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div><span class="icon aui-ss-icon noloading drop-menu"><span>More</span></span><img class="aui-ss-entity-icon" alt="" src="/servicedesk/issue-type-icons?icon=it-help"></div>
<input autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="text aui-ss-field ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" id="issueTypeKey-field" type="text" aria-controls="issueTypeKey-suggestions">
<div class="aui-list" id="issueTypeKey-suggestions" tabindex="-1" role="listbox"></div>
<span class="icon aui-ss-icon noloading drop-menu"><span>More</span></span>
</div>
<select class="select imagebacked aui-ss-select" data-edit-value="" name="issueTypeId" id="issueTypeKey" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;"><option value="10000" style="background-image: url(/servicedesk/issue-type-icons?icon=it-help);">IT Help</option><option value="10001" style="background-image: url(/servicedesk/issue-type-icons?icon=purchase);">Purchase</option><option value="10002" style="background-image: url(/servicedesk/issue-type-icons?icon=fault);">Fault</option><option value="10003" style="background-image: url(/servicedesk/issue-type-icons?icon=access);">Access</option></select>
</td>
<td class="request-type-description"><textarea class="textarea-cell" name="description"></textarea></td>
<td class="request-type-actions"><div><input type="submit" class="aui-button aui-button-primary create-request-type-button" value="Create request type" resolved=""></div></td>
```

Java selenium

```
Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='issueTypeKey-single-select']/")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Fault");
```

The option that I want to choose is called "Fault".

Note that I cannot use "Select" feature as my HTML is "input"

Any suggestions please?

Comment: your HTML is not complete, where is this "Fault"? Need you to provide all the HTML codes including "drop down list" and this option "Fault".

Comment: @Yu Zhang, Thank You! I have just edited the question with complete HTML and option "Fault" :)

Comment: Your HTML still misses some parts, for example, where is </input>? You can use xpath to find your element.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Selenium WebDriver - Filling In Forms documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms). Moreover your id. `issueTypeKey-single-select` is not inside the HTML - you probably want to access `issueTypeKey`. And this has `display: none;`, which should be visible to interact with

```
Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='issueTypeKey']")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Fault");
```

Comment: I am still getting an error :( Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@id='issueTypeKey']/ because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@id='issueTypeKey']/' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Edited above - try again.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with some non-native select elements before and have had good luck with simply clicking on the "input" and then clicking on the option once it pops up. Note that you probably need to wait for the option to be visible as the element location and the page showing the select dropdown options create a race condition. Also, when you have an id in your code, it's cleaner to just select by that directly rather than using XPath to select the id. Give the following example a try:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("issueTypeKey-field"));
input.click();
WebElement fault = input.findElement(By.linkText("Fault"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(fault))
                             .click();
```

First the driver clicks on the element with an id of `issueTypeKey-field`. That should bring up the select options. By creating the web driver wait object and using the expected condition, you wait for the element located by the link text to return `true` for it's `isDisplayed` method. Once it returns from the wait, it will then be clicked. The `10` sets the timeout (in seconds) during which the wait will keep trying to check for the element to become visible. If the timeout is reached and the element hasn't become visible, then a `TimeoutException` will be thrown. The example is saving the WebElements as variables to be used later which I typically don't prefer (due to the possibility of StaleElementReferenceExceptions depending on the page) but in this case you will want to restrict the search for the `Fault` element within the input.

Comment: still getting an error :( Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"issueTypeKey-Field"}

Comment: Well that' better than an invalid selector exception ;-) ... it's saying it can't find any web element that has an id of `issueTypeKey-Field`. That seems to be the value in the HTML snippet above. Double check that the value given to the By exactly matches the id in the page ... I've seen issues before with different encodings and invisible characters.

Comment: I found that it is actually id "issueTypeKey-single-select" in HTML, I change your code to WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("issueTypeKey-single-select")); and now it is clicking the drop down menu but not selecting fault?

Comment: Ahh, looking at the HTML code, it might be the case that you actually need to click on the `a` rather than on the `option` (sometimes this type of thing can depend on which libraries and which styles developers use to create web page widgets). Try this instead for the `By` in the selecting of the `Fault` element:

`By.linkText("Fault")`